# how to fetch raw() function enabled content using json in ruby on rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have one rails application where I have one model posts. Post model having two attributes - "title" & "content". I am using [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) for my content. Here is my ckditor snapshot

[image]

When I save something eg- "hi how r u" with bold, itallic, underline etc. Then it save posts content like this `<b><i><u>hi how r u</u><i></b>`. I know the solution in rails. I am using <%= raw(@posts.content) %> to solve this problem. But Now my problem is different. I want to fetch all the posts content from the database by using json. I am doing like this..

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  respond_with(@posts) do |format|
    format.json { render json: @post_names = {:post => @posts.as_json(:only=> :content)} }
  end
 end
```

Now when i go through `http://localhost:3000/posts.json` then it showing like this

```
{"post":[{"content":"hi"},{"content":"hi"},{"content":"<img src=\"https://www.ginfy.com/img/logo.png\">"},{"content":"hi"},{"content":"my health is not good. Please pray for me..<br>"},{"content":"my health is not good. Please pray for me<br>"},{"content":"hello"},{"content":"<img src=\"http://www.ibettertechnologies.com/img/logo.png\">"},{"content":"<u><i><b>hi how r u?</b></i></u><br>"},{"content":"sdfsd"},{"content":"i am going to home. Please pray for my safe jouney"},{"content":"job"},{"content":"dsfdfs"},{"content":"fddf"},{"content":"jd dsbdsj djhj dsjhdfjks"},{"content":"ddd gd fgdfdg"},{"content":"dfslkdfskldfskl dskljdfskldf dskljdfskldfjslk"},{"content":"please pray for me"},{"content":"dfdf"},{"content":"cvxvxdfs"},{"content":"hdbhjds dsjks"},{"content":"s"},{"content":"hi"},{"content":"hu"}]}
```

I want to fetch this json in android. How can I use <%= raw() %> function in json to get correct formatted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Html.fromHtml()` function to escape HTML tags. You can do like this ..

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/text2" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:textStyle="bold" />


   text2.setText(Html.fromHtml(app.getTitle()).toString());
```